# How to pass password when switching user via su username in one line

Tags: bash, shell, password, su

I have an ec2 instance , I connect to it and do the following:

```
[userA@ip-abcd ~]$ ssh my_ec2_instance 
[userA@ip-abcd ~]$ whoami  
userA   
[userA@ip-abcd ~]$pwd   
/home/userA  
[userA@ip-abcd ~]$ cd ~  
[userA@ip-abcd ~]$ pwd  
/home/userA  
[userA@ip-abcd ~]$ ls   
(shows nothing)  
[userA@ip-abcd ~]$ su userB  
Password:  
(I enter the password and the prompt changes to)    

bash-4.2$ pwd  
/home/UserA  

bash-4.2$ cd ~   
bash-4.2$ ls   
A B C D
```

How do I
su - userB and enter password in a single line in a non interactive way?

Why I need to do above:
Above folder B has code which I need to update from git, and I want to call from a jenkins shell script which would

- ssh into the instance
- su user B
- auto enter the password
- git pull origin master
- python wsgi.py

**What I tried:**

```
1) echo actual_password | su userB  
2) su userB -p actual_password 

3) echo userBPassword | su -c whoami userB
```

3. ^ was the closest where in the terminal I can see userBPassword being entered but nothing happens i.e the userB doesn't get activated.

Is there a way to add the password to the `~/.bash_profile` and automatically use that when prompted when the `su - userB` is executed? as exposing passwords is a bad practice?

Comment: As far as I know, su reads the password from the terminal, not from standard input. You could use `expect` to simulate a human user, but why don't you use `sudo` instead? You can configure it so that no password needs to be entered.

Answer (score 2):

Is using `sudo` an option? Then you could do:

```
echo userBPassword | sudo -S -u userB whoami
```

A similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233217/how-to-pass-the-password-to-su-sudo-ssh-without-overriding-the-tty

Comment: And of course that's a great way for anyone who happens to run `ps` at the same time to see the password.

Comment: Of course, generally this is not a good idea. However, as the use case is CI/CD here, it might be OK. Perhaps the OP wants to look into Jenkins's credentials support: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/

Answer (score 2):

You could use keys to avoid passwords. Generate a key pair as userB on your ec2 machine - copy the private key to the machine you login from and store in userA/.ssh/id_rsa_userB_ec2

Edit UserA/.ssh/config to add a new entry like

```
Host ec2
        Hostname my_ec2_instance
        Port 22
        User userB
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_userB_ec2
```

On your ec2 machine, add the public key to the authorized_keys file. You should then just be able to login and change id to userB with `ssh ec2` using the above alias in the config file